How to troubleshoot "no JSON service config provided" response in grpc-go client?
We are getting an error in our client call, I have done some googling and found the page describing what the config is, but I am not sure how it gets "provided" to the client, or why our grpc-go client call does not seem to have access to this service config.
error:
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error parsing service config: no JSON service config provided

grpc client error https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/07078c41e98f244d24eb336789694c11a2ad4a78/service_config.go#L173
doc: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/service_config.md
service config proto: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-proto/blob/master/grpc/service_config/service_config.proto
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks !
(I tried reading the docs and was expecting to find out how to troubleshoot the cause of this error and potential fixes)

Service Config is poorly documented/explained and is a relatively new facility in gRPC and being rolled out to the SDKs and experimental in Go. Service Configs are provided by the service. From your question, I suspect you're using a 3rd-party service. You should contact the service provider as it's possible they've borked your client.
